# on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) flutter firebase didn't work

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to create the Forgot Password feature on my app using an input email address with conditions like this:

1. If the e-mail account is registered, send a reset password to this e-mail
2. If the e-mail account is not registered, show the message that the email is not registered

The email reset was successful when I filled in the input email, which was **registered**.

But why when I filled in the input email which was **not registered** the message error (on point 2) didn't show?

The output of this code is :
*W/System  ( 6456): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.*

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ForgotPasswordPage extends StatefulWidget {

   const ForgotPasswordPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

   @override
   State<ForgotPasswordPage> createState() => _ForgotPasswordPageState();
}

class _ForgotPasswordPageState extends State<ForgotPasswordPage> {
final _emailController = TextEditingController();

@override
void dispose() {
  _emailController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}


Future passwordReset() async {
  try {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(
    email: _emailController.text.trim(),
  );

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Text('email reset berhasil dikirim'),
      );
    },
  );
  
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Text(e.message.toString()),
      );
    },
  );   
}
```

This is where the function call on MaterialButton() :

```
//email textfield1
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 25.0,
        ),
        child: TextField(
          controller: _emailController,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            ),
            hintText: 'Email',
            fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
            filled: true,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 20,
      ),
      MaterialButton(
        onPressed: passwordReset,
        child: Text('Reset Password'),
        color: Colors.deepPurple[200],
      ),
```

Comment: just show the message when getting an exception, instated of this Text(e.message.toString())